# small AC commutator motor issue

Tags: motor, ac, universal-motor

I have a small vacuum cleaner motor, single-phase, AC commutator motor, 120V, 4 A Max., series wired (all coils, brushes connected in series), no start capacitor, two-pole field stator, with thermal fuse in series with circuit and taped against one of the field coils.

My issue is this: Originally not working/no power. I tracked down the problem to a blown thermal fuse. In the process of removal, I damaged one of the stator pole coils (they are apparently aluminum wire, so more fragile than copper). I decided to remove all the aluminum coil wiring and rewind both field stator coils with enameled copper magnet wire. After re-winding the coils and putting the armature/stator assembly back together, I tested it before complete re-assembly by using wired jumper/test clips to join unconnected wiring points.

It started and ran well--running it for 2 hours as a test. When I went to re-assemble, and soldering the wires to connect, I energized the motor again, but it moved only a small fraction of a rotation, then froze in place and sat there humming. There was no physical restriction on rotation-- it always turned smoothly by hand. I checked and rechecked various aspects of the motor a number times, such as brushes, commutator, connections but could find no obvious reason or change from when it ran upon first trial.

Can anyone offer any possible reasons why motor not now working when worked on first power up? What am I missing?

Comment: During your two hour test, what was the load on the motor?

Comment: Did you make sure that on your final assembly that pole phasing is correct? Does it have a start capacitor or a phase-shift copper insert? Btw I cleaned up your question a bit and broke it into paragraphs by their context.

Comment: @Sparky256, he says in the first paragraph that it is a brushed motor with no start capacitor.

Comment: @replete. That means there is a copper insert in the rotor that creates a phase shift so the motor will rotate, assuming the winding's are phased correctly. A reversed winding will stop the rotation cold. It will likely overheat as it cannot rotate to move air through it.

Comment: @Sparky256 A universal motor needs no copper insert, but the two stator windings do need to be phased correctly with respect to each other.

Comment: @Sparky256 you're describing a shaded-pole induction motor, which does not have brushes or a commutator like the OP's universal motor does.

Comment: @brhans. Then a leaves us with the possibility that one of the winding's is reversed.

Comment: First, I was not able to measure the current.  Second, you guys are correct that I pointed out that this small motor has no start cap.

Comment: I rewound both stator field coils.  And as mentioned, the motor ran when power was first applied after finishing the rewinds of the stator coils, but after securing the final connections using solder it then did NOT work, starting with a partial jerk of a rotation, then stuck with no rotation and humming.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the suggestion of a reversed winding/reversed phasing in one of the stator coils that I wound. This situation I am unfamiliar with, and if important, was not aware or knowledgeable on exactly how the coils should be wound with respect to each other.  However, I again point out that it ORIGINALLY ran, for 2 hours straight, when I first applied power after the rewinds.  If it was a 'reversed winding'/phase shift issue, why would it run originally at all??

Comment: Second question: if it should be a phase-shift/reversed coil wind situation, what would be the procedure to properly wind the coils with respect to each other (and with respect to the armature/rotor windings)?

Comment: IF anyone has specific info on a solution, shoot me an email with info or a source of info: behr121002@gmail.com.  Thanks!

Comment: Having looked closer at some of the comments, a question: would simply reversing the wires of one of the coils cure the problem?  After thinking about it, I suppose that I MIGHT have POSSIBLY NOT secured the wires in the same configuration or sequence as when I first tested it using jumper wires. I suppose it's possible that two wires got transposed which created an phase situation that locks the rotor when power applied. I assume reversing the wires of one of the coils would cure problem.  Yes???

Comment: At any rate, I appreciate all your helpful comments and expertise.  Thanks all!

Comment: Thank you Charles, appreciate your help.  I think your first suggestion is probably correct, since mechanically, it is sound with no play in the rotor and not binding or contacting the sides of the stator field laminations. Manually, it rotates freely.

Comment: I moved my comment to my answer. and also added about reversing the armature with respect to the field. If you have further comments for me, commenting at my answer will help me see the comment more quickly.

Answer (score 4):

When you permanently connected the field coils, you must have reversed one with respect to the other. In conjunction with the armature, one field coil is trying to make the motor turn in one direction and the other is trying to make it turn in the opposite direction. The result is a "frozen" rotor.

If the problem is the two field coils magnetically opposing each other, the correction would be to transpose the two wires of one field winding.

I think that a reversed field winding connection the most likely problem, but it is possible that there is some looseness in the mechanical construction that allows the rotor to move and mechanically bind up when energized.

Note that reversing the armature connection with respect to the field will reverse the direction of rotation.

**Failure Due to Excess Speed**

It has been suggested that a universal motor that is tested without a load might fail because of excess speed. The speed of a universal increases drastically when the load is reduced. With a vacuum cleaner, blocking the air flow stops the air flow and reduces the load to nearly zero because the blower is stirring the air internally rather than moving a mass of air. You can hear the sound of the motor increasing in volume and pitch when that happens. That accelerates the wear in the motor bearings and commutator. It also increases the stress on the rotor parts.

When the motor is removed from the driven machine, there is a danger that the speed will be excessive, but the speed is still limited by the commutator and bearing friction plus the aerodynamic drag of the rotor parts, often including small fan blades on the rotor provided for internal cooling.

If a motor fails due to excess speed, it is unlikely to die quickly or quietly without leaving evidence of failure. If anyone wants to see and hear what that kind of failure looks and sounds like, demonstrations can be found on you-tube. If you want to experience the smell, I recommend that you burn something that is unlikely to fly apart and hurt someone.